# Reading Enviornment variables in Spring application context

Tags: spring

I have three enviornment variables.
MY_TOPIC
MY_CONTEXT_FACTORY
MY_LDAP

First one - MY_TOPIC works like this

```
<bean id="myPublishTopic" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>fxClientDestinationUID=${MY_TOPIC}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Last two does not work reading from enviornment variables. How do it make this work?

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
         <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${MY_CONTEXT_FACTORY}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${MY_LDAP}</prop>
         </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Last two works only if i read it from properties file which i want to avoid.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"><value>/WEB-INF/classes/springConfig-devel.properties</value></property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 3+ you can use Spring Expression Language.

Use `#{systemEnvironment['NAME']}` to access environment variables

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">#{systemEnvironment['MY_CONTEXT_FACTORY']}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">#{systemEnvironment['MY_LDAP']}</prop>
         </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Use `#{systemProperties['value']}` for Java system properties.

Comment: I am using Spring 2.5.6 Any solution for that?

Comment: I think you will need to use a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with `searchSystemEnvironment` set to `true`. I would recommend upgrading to a newer version of Spring (if possible).